# Terraform read secret that was just created

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So I am new to terraform and have been reading along some postings on how to create certain items in AWS. I have been able to write the code to create my RDS' instances fairly easy.  I know i can use Secrets Manager to handle the creation and the management of the RDS instance by inputing this item.

manage_master_user_password   = true

Well I am trying to create a multi-tenant Oracle DB and you can't use this feature so I had to write some code create a password and insert it into Secrets Manager for storage and references.  I can enter the password but when I want to retrieve it in the same Terraform project I seem to be hitting a wall.  I receive this error.

```
│ Error: Secrets Manager Secret "removed for various reasons the arn" Version "AWSCURRENT" not found
│
│   with data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.creds,
│   on main.tf line 153, in data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "creds":
│  153: data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "creds" {
```

In my main.tf I have this code that creates the code in Secrets Manager.

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "this" {
  name_prefix = "education"
  tags = {
    owner          = "edu"
    environment    = "dev"
    technical-name = "education"
  }
}

resource "terraform_data" "create_secret_version" {
  triggers_replace = [
    aws_secretsmanager_secret.this.id
  ]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = <<-EOT
      # Generate a random 16-character base64-encoded password
      PASSWORD=$(openssl rand -base64 16)
      # Create a JSON object with username and password
      SECRET_JSON=$(echo '{"username": "${var.master_user_name}", "password": "'$PASSWORD'" }')
      # Store the JSON object in AWS Secrets Manager
      aws secretsmanager put-secret-value \
        --secret-id ${aws_secretsmanager_secret.this.id} \
        --secret-string "$SECRET_JSON"
    EOT
    interpreter = ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
  }
  depends_on = [aws_secretsmanager_secret.this]
}
```

Now I want to retrieve it.  So I run this in the same main.tf file.

```
# Importing the AWS secrets created previously using arn.
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secretmasterDB" {
  arn = "${aws_secretsmanager_secret.this.arn}"
}

# Importing the AWS secret version created previously using arn.
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "creds" {
  
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.this.id

}
```

When I try this I get that error.  I have tried by putting it into multiple TF files and then all of it into the main.tf file.  My question is if in terraform the reads happen before the creation of objects.  Also, am I doing this correctly?  Also in my reading of how modules work would this help me "order" how things are done in my Terraform project? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Both managing and read the same object in a single configuration is possible in principle, but can cause problems because:

- You need to make sure Terraform can understand that it must wait until after the object has been created/updated before reading it. (I think you've done that in this case.)
- Some remote APIs don't guarantee read-after-write consistency, and so there might be some delay after an object is created or updated before you can read back the new data.

To avoid both of these problems, you should typically *not* have both a `data` block and a `resource` block referring to the same object. Instead, you can access the attributes of the `resource` object directly. The object associated with the `resource` block is usually populated with the result of the "create" API call directly, and so it should be populated even when the API does not guarantee read-after-write consistency.

The example configuration you shared is actually already doing that: you've referred to `aws_secretsmanager_secret.this.id` instead of `data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secretmasterDB`. Therefore I think if you just delete the `data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secretmasterDB"` block you will have a working configuration, assuming that you've included all parts of your current configuration in your question.

Comment: Ok so I removed that section you suggested.  I then want to get the password itself from secrets manager so I can create my Oracle RDS instance.  When I try to pull that secret I get the error I posted in the original post.  So how do I tell terraform to wait to get that password?  It actually creates the password cause even with that error?

Comment: I think the fact that you are using a provisioner to create an object here is making things harder to describe to Terraform, because Terraform can't tell that the `terraform_data` resource is creating a new object. If there's any way to do that step using a real resource type in the AWS provider instead then I'd recommend doing that, but if you absolutely can't avoid using a provisioner then I suppose you'll need to add `depends_on = [terraform_data.create_secret_version]` inside your `data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "creds"` block so that Terraform understands the required ordering.

Answer (score 1):

I learned about modules and how they work and the depends_on.  Now If I create an access_secret and create_secret module and make the access_secret module depend on the create secret one they get created in the correct order and I don't get the error.